# puppet and inline_epp and using hiera deliver content

Tags: puppet, epp

It's possible to use inline_epp's using string variable like this ?

```
                    "htaccess": {
                    "content": [
                        "<% include stdlib -%>",
                        "AuthType Basic ",
                        "AuthUserFile <%= $auth_file %>",
                        "Require valid-use"
                    ],
                    "params": {
                        "auth_name": "Bootstrap content for provisioning",
                        "auth_file": "file_path"
                    }
                }
```

and (some.pp):

```
                $htacces = $sub_attrs['htaccess']
                $content = $htacces['content']
                $data = join($content, "\n")

                $auth_file = "sgsdgsdfgsdfg"

                notice inline_epp($data)
```

> This is result in the notice line : Invalid EPP: This Name has no
>   effect. A value was produced and then forgotten (one or more preceding
>   expressions may have the wrong form)

Idea is use hiera data  to deliver content to epp . 
Using puppet 5.5.2 and Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

There looks like there are a few things going on here.

For one thing, is the syntax of that `notice` function correct? The [Puppet Cookbook](https://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/simple-debug-messages.html) shows `notice` with either brackets `notice("message")` or in Puppet's class syntax `notify { "message": }`).

Also, `inline_epp` takes a hash of the parameters used to fill in the EPP. See the [Puppet documentation on `inline_epp`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#inlineepp). In your case, that'd be something like `inline_epp($data, { auth_file => $auth_file })`.

And lastly, EPP needs a line at the top listing its parameters. In your case it should be something like `<%- | String $auth_file | -%>`. See the [Puppet documentation on EPP files](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/lang_template_epp.html).